# Date to Appear If Same Month

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2013

This might be a simple problem for you :)

I need a formula that will recognise if the month ends or a new one starts in order to stop showing the next month. So, for example, if the month ends in 30, then nothing appears in the next cell, if the month goes to 31, then the 31 appears there. That is needed because the month is changing automatically in each of those boxes and I need to account for that change. How can I achieve that in Excel 2013? I tried a few if formulas, but they didn't work. Your help is appreciated.

[image]

Comment: Autofilter on date value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this formula:

```
=IFERROR(IF(MONTH(B2+1)=MONTH(B2),B2+1,""),"")
```

After inserting the first day of the month, enter the formula on the next cell. Drag it down to fill the other cells.

It checks if the month of the current and previous cell are the same. If yes, the date is displayed; if not, it is not shown.

[image: IMG:]

Answer (score 0):

Try this formula:

```
=IFERROR(IF(A1=EOMONTH(A1,0),"",A1+1),"")
```

[image]